# How to verify downloaded file format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, file-format

My server can store files with *.pdf extension.
Should I check the file format *or* right extension is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot, Bob! Your solution is great. I parse remote file, and change your reg exp a bit:

```
file_url = 'http://...../file_name.pdf'
file = open(file_url)
contents = file.read(10)
is_pdf = (contents =~ /\%PDF-\d+\.?\d+/) == 0
render :text => is_pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension isn't sufficient to prove that a file has the right format.  You could name anything .pdf.  It's in the opening and reading of the file that the formatting is checked (whether by the application itself or some other means of verifying).

Answer (score 0):

Shadowland is right, a quick check will save a lot of pain later.  If I had a dime for every time a customer said "I DID use a PDF.  I took my Word file, changed the name to 'pdf,' and mailed it!" I'd have enough for a cup of coffee.

Here's a quick check, if you don't want to use a full-blown PDF-handling gem at upload time.  According to [Adobe's PDF spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), every PDF file should begin with

```
%PDF−<version-number>
```

For example, a PDF version 1.7 file will begin with

```
%PDF−1.7
```

Without over-engineering a future-proof solution (what happens when we reach PDF spec version 10.0?), I'd try reading the beginning of the file and make sure that it's of the form...

```
%PDF-<digit>.<digit>
```

Or, to write that in Ruby (using error-safe blocks and regexp's,)...

```
contents = File.open('Full_path_to_my_file', 'r') { |f| f.read(8)}
is_pdf = (contents =~ /\%PDF-\d\.\d/) == 0
```

Comment: I took my Word file, changed the name to 'pdf,' and mailed it! +1))

Comment: Adobe Acrobat doesn't require PDF files to start with %PDF-d.d. It can be anywhere in the first 1024 bytes.